# dte.ExecuteCommand "Edit.Find" cannot find quotation marks?

Tags: vba, visual-studio

```
MSVS_versions = Array _
( _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.7", _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.7.1", _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.8.0", _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.9.0", _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.10.0", _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.11.0", _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.12.0", _
    "VisualStudio.DTE.14.0" _
)

For each version in MSVS_versions
    Err.Clear
    Set dte = getObject(,version)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set dte = WScript.CreateObject("VisualStudio.DTE")
    Err.Clear
End If


dte.MainWindow.Activate
dte.MainWindow.Visible = True
dte.UserControl = True

dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile filename
if keyword is not nothing then
    dte.ExecuteCommand "Edit.Find", """"
end if
```

I have this vba code. I'm interested in the second last line. I want to find a quotation mark in the current docurnet. When I run the code, Visual Studio tells me

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The search pattern is invalid.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How do I search quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters that `dte.ExecuteCommand` accepts are what we can input in Visual Studio's Command Window.

[image]

Command Window gives the same error as the OP found.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-window#escape-characters states the escape character is <kbd>^</kbd>, thus you have to use `dte.ExecuteCommand "Edit.Find", "^"""` in order to find `"`.

As of all parameters of `Edit.Find`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/find-command